# use csv parameters in jmeter httprequest path

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I want to use CSV Data Set Config to modify the path of a HTTP Request.

- My CSV file:

  ```
  120,120
  121,121
  ```
- My CSV variable names: `paraa, parab`.
- My http request path: `/my/path/with/?{paraa}/?{parab}/`.

I tried and I failed.

Is there anyway to work this around?

Comment: Can I ask why you haven't accepted answers to any of your previous questions? That's very important here on SE, both for building knowledge base and your credibility.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems that you incorrectly refer jmeter variables.
Try

```
/my/path/with/${paraa}/${parab}/
```

instead,
where `${paraa}, ${parab}` refer corresponding values extracted in CSV Data Set Config:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have 2 variables in my csv file Username and Password I setup as you mentioned above and put these variable in my login request ${Username} and ${Password}, but when i am running my script it only puts Username but not password.Can you please tell me how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Well, what have you already tried to find the cause of your issue: looked into jmeter.log / Options -> Log Viewer for possible error messages, tried [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) / [Debug PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) to ensure that your variables values are (not) correctly extracted from csv, used any listener to track values sent along with requests and responses received?