# Jmeter CSV data config doesn't identify the userid and password in csv file

Tags: jmeter

I have created a CSV file and placed in /bin directory and added csv data config file with paramaters `UID` and `PWD` but when I run the test it does not show the user id and password. Despite, in the csv file it shows as `txtlogin=<EOF>&txtpassword=<EOF>`.

Why isn't it picking the given userids and password?

Comment: If you prefer video tutorials, I have created one , explaining how to use csv data set with example test plan. Here you go http://tutorials.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-5cc9f26b-b05b-4258-82ef-df275c103167/t/csv-data-set-jmeter-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You should place your csv file where you saved your test script file. Normally test script can be saved as with jmx extension and placed your csv file in the same directory of it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have put your CSV file in parallel of your saved result file, I have solved my problem with this while getting EOF error. :)

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800525/993246) how to read and refer variables from csv.

And look into `%JMETER_HOME%/bin/jmeter.log` if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the fully qualified path of the CSV file to ensure JMeter can find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting  in my variable values when I had ./mycsvfile.csv as the path.  I took the ./ off the front and it started working.  My csv file is in the same directory as my .jmx test script file.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into the same issues. It seems to be a bug. 
Don't name your .csv file "user.csv" or "users.csv". They seem to be reserved names.

I changed the name of the file and then it worked.